# Scripting input to XSL Transformation in XML Tools plugin for Notepad++

Tags: python, xml, xslt, plugins, notepad++

I'm using the Python Script plugin (http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net) for Notepad++ to do some automated tasks with XML files. I've been able to use the XSL Transformation function in the XML Tools plugin from the script I wrote, but only to get the popup to appear, not to input a path to the .xsl file and set off the transform.

Here's my code to open an XML file then get the XSL Transformation window to pop up (in Python, running from Python Script in Notepad++):

```
notepad.open(xmlFilePath)
notepad.runMenuCommand("XML Tools", "XSL Transformations")
#I have a time.sleep(30) here so I can manually input the XSL file
notepad.saveAs(htmlFilePath)
notepad.close()
```

How would I go about being able to fill in the .xsl path automatically and simulate the button press to set off the transform?